# How to share an image with Discordrb Api?

Tags: ruby, discord

I'm coding a Discord Bot with the Discordrb Api, and I can't find a way to share an image on my computer to discord.

```rb
bot.command :food do |event|      
  agent = Mechanize.new
  link = 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/featured/?Food'
  agent.get(link).save "images/pic.jpg"        
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok so I've found a way to do that

```
bot.command :food do |event|

    agent = Mechanize.new
    link = 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/featured/?Food,Plate'
    agent.get(link).save "pic.png" 
    event.send_file(File.open('pic.png', 'r'), caption: "Voiçi votre repas #
    {event.user.name} .")
    sleep(5)
    event File.delete("pic.png")

end
```

I hope that this can help some people.

[Channel#send_file](http://discordrb.github.io/discordrb/master/Discordrb/Channel.html#send_file-instance_method)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add as answer to this question, that if you're sending a image that's stored online, you might want to simply send an embed instead.

```rb
bot.command :food do |event|
  event.channel.send_embed("Check out the image below") do |embed|
    embed.image = Discordrb::Webhooks::EmbedImage.new(url: "https://source.unsplash.com/random/featured/?Food,Plate")
  end
end
```

[Channel#send_embed](http://discordrb.github.io/discordrb/master/Discordrb/Channel.html#send_embed-instance_method)

[Embed](http://discordrb.github.io/discordrb/master/Discordrb/Webhooks/Embed.html)